# How can check the OnCollisionEnter2D Continuous

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have an animation and two 2D game object one line and one box. Line has a animation about transformation x. Shortly, Line go to right side through the box and restart. I was try when the line crash the box play the audio. This system work via  void OnCollisionEnter2D. But its work only one time. OnCollisionEnter2D is doesnt checking the crash every time. So, how can I solve the logic problem.

[image: Visual]

```
public AudioClip A1;
public bool b1;

  void Update(){

    if (b1 == true) {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (A1, transform.position);
    }

}

void  OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Button1")

        b1 = true;

}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll){
if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Button1")
        b1 = false;

}
```

Comment: I didnt select the true answer yet because my project doesnt noticed the crash any type of method anymore. I didnt change anything. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D)** you can play your animation in this function.

```
public AudioClip A1;

void  OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Button1")
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (A1, transform.position);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnCollisionStay2D, it will check the crash every time

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Button1")
            b1 = true;

    }
}
```